# AngularJS not displaying object correctly in ng-repeat on iOS only with Onsen framework

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have a list, where I use ng-repeat to go through an object collection that looks something like this:

```
$scope.PMStatuses = {};
$scope.PMStatuses["Status1"] = { status: "Status1" };
$scope.PMStatuses["Status2"] = { status: "Status2" };
$scope.PMStatuses["Status3"] = { status: "Status3" };
```

This is in the controller, and now the view looks something like this:

```
...
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item ng-repeat="taskstatus in PMStatuses" modifier="tappable" ng-click="SelectStatus(taskstatus .status);">
        {{taskstatus .status}}
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
...
```

Whenever I bring up the view, and bring up this list, I don't see the actual status values being displayed, but {{tstatus .status}} for every item. However, if I tap them, I can see that the right item is being selected.

This only happens on iOS. Android and the web browser display it correctly.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You don't have a list (or array), you have an object. Can you try putting them in an array instead?

Comment: it's an object collection. I use the same principle for every other collection where I use ng-repeat, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: It's an object with properties, `$scope.PMStatuses.Status1 = { status: "Status1" };` would be the same thing. I know that it often works, but according to the documentation you should use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj"` when iterating over object properties. Worth testing with an array first to rule out that this is the problem.

Comment: I tried converting PMStatuses = {}; to an array, like this: $scope.PMStatuses = ['Status1', 'Status2', 'Status3']; but I get the same reaction...